# Generate all possible subsets of a given set and do some calculations

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
subj trial  factor   rt
1     1     Early    324 
1     2     Early    405 
1     3     Early    293 
1     4     Early    738 
1     5     Late     310 
1     6     Late     389 
1     7     Late     350 
1     8     Late     782 
1     9     Late     513 
1    10     Late     401 
2     1     Early    420 
2     2     Early    230 
2     3     Early    309 
2     4     Late     456 
2     5     Late     241 
2     6     Late     400 
2     7     Late     189 
2     8     Late     329 
2     9     Late     519 
2    10     Late     230 
3     1     Early    299 
3     2     Early    499 
3     3     Late     403 
3     4     Late     389 
3     5     Late     356 
3     6     Late     365 
3     7     Late     234 
3     8     Late     345 
3     9     Late     300 
3     10    Late     402
```

As you can see there are unequal number of trials for both conditions.

What I want to do is for each participant, calculate the number of trials per condition (For participant 1 it would be Early = 3 and Late = 7, for participant 2 is Early = 4, Late = 6, and participant 3 is Early = 2 and Late 8).

The number of trials of Early condition will determine the size of the subsets I want to generate. So again, for participant 1, I want to generate all the possible combinations of 3 trials out of the 7 trials in the Late condition and calculate a mean for each combination. I don't know if I'm explaining it correctly.

So, it would go something like this. Since participant 1 only has 3 trials in the early condition, I will calculate a mean rt score for those 3 trials. But for the late condition, I want to generate all possible combinations of trials like 4 5 6, 4 5 7, 4 5 8, 4 5 9, 4 5 10, 4 6 7, 4 6 8, 4 6 9, 4 6 10 etc and then calculate the mean rt score for each combination of trials and then a general mean for the late condition.

I don't know how to go about doing this. I know expand.grid() function can help with the combination part, but I don't really know how to make the number of combinations be defined by the number of trials of the early condition since this will vary for each participant.

I don't know if I was clear enough, but I hope someone can help shade some light on it.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution. You can define a customized function `combavg` to calculate the mean of combinations

```
combavg <- function(x) {
  r <- data.frame(t(combn(which(x$factor == "Late"),sum(x$factor == "Early"), function(v) c(v,mean(x$rt[v])))))
  names(r)[ncol(r)] <- "rt.avg"
  r
}
```

and then use the following line to get the result

```
res <- Map(combavg,split(df,df$subj))
```

such that

```
> res
$`1`
   X1 X2 X3 X4 rt.avg
1   5  6  7  8 457.75
2   5  6  7  9 390.50
3   5  6  7 10 362.50
4   5  6  8  9 498.50
5   5  6  8 10 470.50
6   5  6  9 10 403.25
7   5  7  8  9 488.75
8   5  7  8 10 460.75
9   5  7  9 10 393.50
10  5  8  9 10 501.50
11  6  7  8  9 508.50
12  6  7  8 10 480.50
13  6  7  9 10 413.25
14  6  8  9 10 521.25
15  7  8  9 10 511.50

$`2`
   X1 X2 X3   rt.avg
1   4  5  6 365.6667
2   4  5  7 295.3333
3   4  5  8 342.0000
4   4  5  9 405.3333
5   4  5 10 309.0000
6   4  6  7 348.3333
7   4  6  8 395.0000
8   4  6  9 458.3333
9   4  6 10 362.0000
10  4  7  8 324.6667
11  4  7  9 388.0000
12  4  7 10 291.6667
13  4  8  9 434.6667
14  4  8 10 338.3333
15  4  9 10 401.6667
16  5  6  7 276.6667
17  5  6  8 323.3333
18  5  6  9 386.6667
19  5  6 10 290.3333
20  5  7  8 253.0000
21  5  7  9 316.3333
22  5  7 10 220.0000
23  5  8  9 363.0000
24  5  8 10 266.6667
25  5  9 10 330.0000
26  6  7  8 306.0000
27  6  7  9 369.3333
28  6  7 10 273.0000
29  6  8  9 416.0000
30  6  8 10 319.6667
31  6  9 10 383.0000
32  7  8  9 345.6667
33  7  8 10 249.3333
34  7  9 10 312.6667
35  8  9 10 359.3333

$`3`
   X1 X2 rt.avg
1   3  4  396.0
2   3  5  379.5
3   3  6  384.0
4   3  7  318.5
5   3  8  374.0
6   3  9  351.5
7   3 10  402.5
8   4  5  372.5
9   4  6  377.0
10  4  7  311.5
11  4  8  367.0
12  4  9  344.5
13  4 10  395.5
14  5  6  360.5
15  5  7  295.0
16  5  8  350.5
17  5  9  328.0
18  5 10  379.0
19  6  7  299.5
20  6  8  355.0
21  6  9  332.5
22  6 10  383.5
23  7  8  289.5
24  7  9  267.0
25  7 10  318.0
26  8  9  322.5
27  8 10  373.5
28  9 10  351.0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(subj = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), trial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), factor = c("Early", "Early", "Early", 
"Early", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Early", 
"Early", "Early", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", 
"Late", "Early", "Early", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", "Late", 
"Late", "Late", "Late"), rt = c(324L, 405L, 293L, 738L, 310L, 
389L, 350L, 782L, 513L, 401L, 420L, 230L, 309L, 456L, 241L, 400L, 
189L, 329L, 519L, 230L, 299L, 499L, 403L, 389L, 356L, 365L, 234L, 
345L, 300L, 402L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L
))
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code splits the data set by `subj` and `lapply` a function to each subset. This function `fun` uses `combn` to determine the combinations of indices when `factor == "Late"` and computes the mean value of each `rt` indexed by those combinations.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  n <- sum(DF[["factor"]] == "Early")
  late <- which(DF[["factor"]] == "Late")
  cmb <- combn(late, n)
  apply(cmb, 2, function(i) mean(DF[i, "rt"]))
}

sp <- split(df1, df1$subj)
lapply(sp, fun)
#$`1`
# [1] 457.75 390.50 362.50 498.50 470.50 403.25 488.75
# [8] 460.75 393.50 501.50 508.50 480.50 413.25 521.25
#[15] 511.50
#
#$`2`
# [1] 365.6667 295.3333 342.0000 405.3333 309.0000 348.3333
# [7] 395.0000 458.3333 362.0000 324.6667 388.0000 291.6667
#[13] 434.6667 338.3333 401.6667 276.6667 323.3333 386.6667
#[19] 290.3333 253.0000 316.3333 220.0000 363.0000 266.6667
#[25] 330.0000 306.0000 369.3333 273.0000 416.0000 319.6667
#[31] 383.0000 345.6667 249.3333 312.6667 359.3333
#
#$`3`
# [1] 396.0 379.5 384.0 318.5 374.0 351.5 402.5 372.5 377.0
#[10] 311.5 367.0 344.5 395.5 360.5 295.0 350.5 328.0 379.0
#[19] 299.5 355.0 332.5 383.5 289.5 267.0 318.0 322.5 373.5
#[28] 351.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Rudi Barradas